# database design -- many to many table - how to best represent

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to represent a many-to-many relationship between teachers and the subjects that they teach.

For implementation, a couple of strategies come to mind:

```
 teacher_name | subject_names
 bill           math, english, science, french
 sally        | chemistry, english, arts & crafts
```

I've rejected this strategy because querying fields with comma separated values does not seem efficient, especially when I will be pulling them for search engines, iteration, etc... though I am certainly open to hearing a defense of this strategy

```
 teacher_name | subject_name
 bill           math
 bill           english
 bill           science
 ...            ...
 sally          chemistry
 sally          english
 ...            ...
```

I initially thought this was a better idea, but when I query for information about the teacher, I get data that gets hard to report. i.e. it's fine that I have 5 rows for bob's subjects, but it's not fine that I also find that he lives at 123 main st. and 123 main st. and 123 main st... I still think this is a better idea overall, but maybe a better one exists.

By the way, I don't really use teacher_names and subject_names to index through, I use numbers, but I've drawn it this way for clarity

Comment: At minimal, you should read up on basic database concepts and normalization before you attempt to design anything. Comma seperated fields are NEVER a good idea in databases.

Answer (score 2):

Many-to-many relationships are best solved using a third table called a **Junction Table** that maps the relations. Here's a [good guide](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php) that explains a little more in detail, but basically...

The new table table will contain two columns of foreign keys; the unique ID (primary key of the teachers-table) of your teachers in one column, and subjects unique ID (primary key of the subjects-table) in the the other column (... and of course a column for the junction table's it's own unique ID).

Say this is your **table of teachers**:

```
----------------------------
| ID   | Name  | Last_Name |
----------------------------
| 0001 | JOHN  | STEPHENS  |
----------------------------
| 0002 | BRUCE | WAYNE     |
----------------------------
```

And this is your **table of subjects**

```
-----------------------
| ID   | Subject_name |
-----------------------
| 0101 | MATH         |
-----------------------
| 0202 | BIOLOGY      |
-----------------------
| 0303 | ENGLISH      |
-----------------------
```

Then you need a junction table like this:

**TeacherSubject_JunctionTable**:

```
--------------------------------
| ID | Teacher_ID | Subject_ID |
--------------------------------
| 01 | 0001       | 0101       |
--------------------------------
| 02 | 0001       | 0202       |
--------------------------------
| 03 | 0002       | 0101       |
--------------------------------
| 04 | 0002       | 0303       |
--------------------------------
```

Now, whenever you need to get a list of teachers that teach math (subject_id 0101), you can simply query the juction table; something like

```
SELECT Teacher_ID FROM TeacherSubject_JunctionTable
WHERE Subject_ID = 0101;
```

Or the other way around, if you want to get the subjects that a teacher teach.

Comment: That all seems to make sense, but I am wondering what the ID field is for in the TeacherSubject_JunctionTable. When would that number be useful to have?

Comment: Good point, and you're absolutely right - there's no problem in leaving it out (and many choose to do so). I usually like to have an ID field anyway, since I find it nice to having an easy way to refer to a row, and to be honest, it's very unlikely that the amount of disk space an ID-field takes up would be a concern. But a junction table is really mostly an implementation detail rather than an entity in it's own right, so (depending on how you like your databases) leaving it out is a perfectly reasonable thing to do. Mostly a matter of taste, really.

Comment: Although it's not as "pure" an implementation of a Junction Table, sometimes extra information about the relationship between the two elements can be added, and at that point I think it's quite useful to have an ID-field. Consider a table, `SALE` - it could be thought of as a JT describing the relationship between the tables  `ITEM` and `CUSTOMER`  - and you might want to add a `Timestamp`-field to that table to show when it was purchased, and maybe a discount-percentage, who knows. Purists might disagree that this is still a JT, but the basic concept remains the same.

Comment: A junction table is also known as a through table in Django.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a table for subjects (id,subject_name) another for teachers (id,teacher_name) and another table called teacher_subject that has teacher_id,subject_id as a composite key. this is the most recommended approach for many to many relationships as it is normalized.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your solutions break normalization stratagies

The normal way to do this is with a 3rd Join Table.

```
teacher_ID | teacher_name | Other stuff about teachers
    1      |     bill     | address, dob etc.
    2      |    sally     | etc.

subject_ID | subject_name | Other stuff about teachers
    1      |    math      | department, campus etc.
    2      |   english    | etc.


teacher_ID | subject_ID   | Other stuff about the relationship
    1      |     4        | location etc.
    1      |     2        | etc.
    2      |     2        | etc.
    2      |     1        | etc.
```

The teacher_ID & subject_ID is an auto-incrementing int primary key in the first 2 tables.
teacher_ID & subject_ID are the primary key of the 3rd.